# Could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need a little help. I'm trying to create UICollectionView with header section, using custom layout for `UICollectionViewCell`(item) and `UICollectionReusableView`(header). Before header, everything was working perfectly, but now for some reason I'm always getting this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason:

 'could not dequeue a view of
 kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier ProductCellView - must register
 a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I have registered both files in CollectionView. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    productsCollectionView.delegate = self
    productsCollectionView.dataSource = self

    productsCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "SectionHeader", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionReusableView");
    productsCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "HomeProductViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ProductCellView")
}
```

And I will post now one block of code which is used for handling view of header section and which is causing crash. If I comment that part of code, collection view will show regular items without header of course. Here it is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    //1
    switch kind {
    //2
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        //3
        if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionReusableView", for: indexPath) as? SectionHeader{

            sectionHeader.categoriesCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CategoryViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoryViewCell")
            sectionHeader.homeImagesCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "HomeImageViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "HomeImageViewCell")

            sectionHeader.homeImagesCollectionView.delegate = self
            sectionHeader.homeImagesCollectionView.dataSource = self

            sectionHeader.categoriesCollectionView.delegate = self
            sectionHeader.categoriesCollectionView.dataSource = self

            // Add icon to button
            let icon = UIImage(named: "magnifying-glass")!
            sectionHeader.btnSearch.setImage(icon, for: .normal)
            sectionHeader.btnSearch.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 20)
            sectionHeader.btnSearch.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            sectionHeader.btnSearch.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            sectionHeader.btnSearch.layer.cornerRadius = 4

            sectionHeader.prepareCategories()
            sectionHeader.prepareHomeImages()

            return sectionHeader
        }
    default:
        //4
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
    return UICollectionReusableView()
}
```

So I'm really desperate here because I have lost almost two days finding bug why this is happening. I would really appreciate if someone point me in the right direction where to look for bug, because I have tried almost everything I knew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the inner collections since you set the delegate & dataSource here

```
sectionHeader.homeImagesCollectionView.delegate = self
sectionHeader.homeImagesCollectionView.dataSource = self
sectionHeader.categoriesCollectionView.delegate = self
sectionHeader.categoriesCollectionView.dataSource = self
```

it asks for

```
 if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionReusableView", for: indexPath) as? SectionHeader{
```

so you have to wrap the whole part inside the type of the collection

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {


   if collectionView == mainCollection {

   }
   else
   if collectionView == homeImagesCollectionView {

   }
   else {   // categoriesCollectionView

   }

}
```

BTW register should be inside `viewDidLoad` for a collection inside a VC , and in `init`/`awakeFromnib` inside a collectionCell custom class

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I'm already registering in viewDidLoad(). I have one collectionview and two inner collectionviews inside header section

Comment: you must register the inner ones also prior to **viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind** , also see the right structure for **viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind**

Comment: I'm not really sure where I should check for collectionview. Inside if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView? because from sectionHeader I can get inner collectionviews

Comment: It is working! Thanks. However now I'm getting duplicated data inside inner collection views

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem when I was fetching my data and reloading the tableview before registering the nibs. This is my best answer given the info you supplied.